# Watir webdriver mouse over (hover) - differences between Firefox Chrome IE

Tags: ruby, webdriver, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to fire a mouse over on a public website with method `.hover`, but it seems to work only on Chrome. Other browsers generate errors or don't display any information.

I tried alternatives methods like Watir's `.fire_event` or `.execute_script` with internal Javascript, but both failed on Firefox and IE. Watir Classic gives the same sort of results.

I don't understand if it's a problem about Watir syntax, about browser specific syntax, or about unsupported browser version.

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

BROWSER = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
BROWSER.goto("http://france.meteofrance.com/")
sleep 10 # wait until flash ads are closed
BROWSER.a(:class, "p593500Content").when_present.hover # works, on Chrome only
puts BROWSER.div(:id, "p593500Content").style # position of div after a.hover: left: 249px; top: 223px;

# Chrome - OK, tooltip displayed
# Firefox 7 to 19 - KO: d is undefined in driver_component.js (sometimes l. 7024, or l. 8587)
# IE8, IE9 - KO (maybe OK with IE7): 'unable to locate element, using {:class=>"p593500Content", :tag_name=>"a"}', nothing occurs
```

Ruby version and Gem list:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

bigdecimal (1.1.0)                  rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
builder (3.2.0)                     rubyzip (0.9.9)
childprocess (0.3.9)                s4t-utils (1.0.4)
commonwatir (4.0.0)                 selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
cucumber (1.2.3)                    subexec (0.2.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.1)                    user-choices (1.1.6.1)
ffi (1.6.0 x86-mingw32)             watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
gherkin (2.11.6 x86-mingw32)        watir-classic (3.6.0)
hoe (3.5.2)                         watir-page-helper (1.0.3)
io-console (0.3)                    watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
json (1.7.7, 1.5.5)                 websocket (1.0.7)
mini_magick (3.5.0)                 win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
minitest (2.5.1)                    win32-process (0.7.1)
multi_json (1.7.2)                  win32screenshot (1.0.8)
nokogiri (1.5.7.rc3 x86-mingw32)    windows-api (0.4.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)                      windows-pr (1.2.2)
rautomation (0.8.0)                 xml-simple (1.1.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
```

Comment: The Firefox problem may This may have to do with support at the Webdriver level. I'm pretty sure driver_component.js is webdriver code.  we might need to deal with that one in a separate question.  But to start can you do a `gem list` command and put that output into the question (at least for versions of anything watir or webdriver releated)

Comment: I added ruby version and gem list in question, also here are my Chrome and IE server version (there is no server for Firefox, I think): 'ChromeDriver port=9515 version=26.0.1383.0' and 'InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 2.31.0.0 Listening on port 5555'.

Comment: From the [notes about WebDriver for IE](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver): "When you attempt to hover over elements, and your physical mouse cursor is within the boundaries of the IE browser window, the hover will not work. More specifically, the hover will appear to work for a fraction of a second, and then the element will revert back to its previous state. ... The WebDriver development team has been unable to discover a workaround for this behavior of IE."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing in IE comes before it tries to hover.  It's saying that it cannot find the thing you want to call hover on.  So you'll need to figure out why that is happening.

Some potential causes:

- The systems running those browsers (or the browsers) are enough slower that the element has not been rendered yet (often by client side javascript or ajax type actions)
- The HTML is different and the item has different attributes. (offhand, that doesn't appear to be the problem in your case at least not based on looking at that site in IE8)
- The HTML is different and the item is in a frame
- Something else is happening, that prevents access to the DOM at that instant, for example maybe you have some kind of modal like the browser is asking to install flash or some kind of plugin or something.
- Something in browser settings prevents the element from being rendered

One thing to try might be to extend the timeout on the when_present action to give it more time

A potential troubleshooting step might be to put a few sleeps before that line, and snap some screenshots at say 10 second intervals, so you can see (at least visually) what the browser has rendered at that point  IS that part of the map up at Nord-Pas-de-Calais rendered?.  Is there a modal popup or some other browser warning?

The FF problem appears to be entirely different based on the error, that seems to be a webdriver problem.

Comment: For IE, I manage to display the hover element with a syntax change, a(:class, "p593500Content") is changed into a(:class, /p593500Content/) or a(:class, /^p593500Content$/). First I thought String value for :class was not processed the same way than regexp, but nothing is mentionned in the 'How and What' from [documentation](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+and+What). Then after a timing test, I noticed it tooks 35s in Chrome and 58s in IE to work (such a pain to wait that long), I know regexp are not fast since the change to Webdriver...

Comment: Finally I forced a 'sleep 70' and the String value for :class worked in IE for a time, but it does not work everytime whereas regexp seems more stable. I tried .when_present(100) and increased b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait but both failed (timed out after 100 seconds, waiting for a to become present). Such side effect is hard to deal with.

Comment: For Firefox, I would try to correct 'undefined variable' error in driver_component.js and retry locally, but did you know where is located the default file driver_component.js that I need to update? Because I think a new profile is created in '.../AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile...' every time I run watir, so the file driver_component.js is recreated everytime.

Comment: Unfortunately I am only minimally familiar with stuff down at the webdriver level.   One reason it may make more sense to split off that problem into a question of its own, and make sure it is tagged with webdriver, or go seeking help on the webdriver group.  I'm pretty good with stuff up at the Watir level, as are a few others here that look for stuff with watir or watir-webdriver tags.  The IE problem is pretty much up at that level since it's more about how to sync with what appears to be a very slow site.

Comment: as I understand it, the implicit wait is going to wait that long for any element to appear in any test.  that can cause a lot of slowness if you have situations where a test is failing, or where you are waiting for something to go away.  you are better off IMHO to have a smaller value for the implicit wait, and specifically override the timeout when needed, or (ugh) use fixed sleeps when you know something always takes x time to process on the back end.